# Guid converted to int32

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview, guid

i'm trying to programmatically add a where clause to the LinqDatasource of my gridview, but i keep getting an exception saying: "Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'Guid' and 'Int32'"

```
if (e.CommandName == "getuser")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);    
        GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[index];
        Guid id = new Guid(selectedRow.Cells[1].Text);

        LinqDataSource2.Where = "UserID = " + id;
        GridView1.DataSourceID = LinqDataSource2.ID;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

anyone know how, when and why my Guid is converted to an int ?

**Fixed**

added a line

```
LinqDataSource2.WhereParameters.Add("UserID", System.Data.DbType.Guid, id.ToString());
```

i'm guessing int32 is a standard type when nothing is set in whereparameters, but only the where. 
Just guessing though, if anyone knows more please inform me.

Comment: A word of advice. When you receive this exception in the debugger it will highlight the line of code that raises the exception. Always tell us which line this is. Otherwise we have to try and guess.

Comment: it always happens at the GridView1.Databind(), even though the error was made earlier, but doesn't show until it tries to bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always with SQL - You're better using the facilities in your data access layer to pass your parameters as their actual type (with appropriate data layer -> database conversions, as required), rather than using a string.

It looks like LinqDataSource has a [WhereParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.whereparameters.aspx) collection, so you'd create your where something like:

```
LinqDataSource2.Where = "UserID = @UserID";
```

And then add an appropriate parameter to the WhereParameters collection. (Note, I've not written such code, just pulled in a few quick details, but it looks right)

Comment: +1 for the most promising way so far.. wasn't aware of such possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll be comparing your id as a string to your GUID, then you'd need to cast the GUID field to a string. The easiest way to achieve this is to call the ToString() method on your GUILD field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LinqDataSource2.Where = "UserID = '" + id.ToString("B") + "'";
```

This will pass the GUID in such form: `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`
Hopefully, that's what the database is expecting.

Comment: "UserID" in the DB is a GUID, id in the c# code is supposed to be a GUID too, but is converted somwhere. 
I don't want "id" to be a string nor int, but a GUID

Comment: But you can't, because the `Where` property of the data source is a string.